# Subset signatures in Alloy argument declarations - are they not checked?

Tags: alloy

I am getting unexpected results in an Alloy model.  Consider the following model which describes a few aspects of responses to HTTP requests:

```
// Code:  an HTTP return code
abstract sig Code {}
one sig rc200, rc301, rc302 extends Code {}

// State:  the current state of a resource
sig State {}

// subsets of State: some resources are green, some red
// (also:  some neither, some both)
sig Green in State {}
sig Red in State {}

// Response:  a return code + state pair
sig Response {
  rc : one Code,
  entity_body : lone State
}

// some subclasses of Response
sig R200_OK in Response {}{ rc = rc200 }
sig R301_Moved_Permanently in Response {}{ rc = rc301 }
sig R302_Found in Response {}{ rc = rc302 }

// a Response is red/green if its entity body is Red/Green
pred green[ R : R200_OK ] { R.entity_body in Green }
pred red[ R : R200_OK ]{ R.entity_body in Red }

assert A {
  all R : Response | green[R] implies R.rc = rc200
}
check A for 3
```

Because the predicates `green` and `red` declare their argument as being of type `R200_OK`, I expect that these predicates will be true only for atoms in the relation `R200_OK`, and other Responses (e.g. a Response with rc = rc301) will satisfy neither predicate.  This expectation is expressed by assertion A.

To my surprise, however, when asked to check assertion A, the Alloy Analyzer produces what it says is a counterexample, involving a Response which is not in the relation R200_OK.  (I first encountered this unexpected behavior in 4.2, build 2012-09-25; the current build of 2014-05-16 behaves the same way.)

Section B.7.3 Declarations of the language reference says "A declaration introduces one or more variables, and constrains their values and type. ... The relation denoted by each variable (on the left) is constrained to be a subset of the relation denoted by the bounding expression (on the right)."  Am I wrong to read this as entailing that the only atoms which should satisfy the predicates `red` and `green` are atoms in the relation R200_OK?  Or is something else going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are checked.

The phenomenon you are pointing out in your question is explained in the Software Abstraction Book page 126.

It's basically written that the type checker will report an error if and only if the type of the argument declared in the predicate and the type of the value given as parameter during invocation are disjoint.
In your case, R200_OK and Response are not disjoint, hence the absence of error.

You could rewrite your predicate as follows :

```
pred green[ R : Response ] {R in R200_OK and R.entity_body in Green }
```

To illustrate the type checker's behavior extensively, you can consider the following example

```
sig A,B extends C{}
sig C{ c: set univ}
pred testExtend[a:A]{
    a.c!= none
}

run {testExtend[A]} // works as expected
run {testExtend[B]} // error as A and B are disjoint
run {testExtend[C]} // no error as A and C are not disjoint

sig D,E in F{}
sig F{ f: set univ}
pred testIn[d:D]{
    d.f!= none
}

run {testIn[D]} // works as expected
run {testIn[E]} // no error as E and D are not disjoint
run {testIn[F]} // no error as E and F are not disjoint
```

I would also like to put under your attention that you use the keyword **in** rather than **extends** , in the declaration of your 3 kinds of responses, which implies that :

- A same response can be of different kind (i.e. a R200_OK response can also be a R302_Found)
- A Response can also be neither R200_OK nor R302_Found, nor R301_Moved_Permanently.

It might not be what you want to express.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to section 4.5.2 (p. 126).  I had inferred from B.7.3 that declarations performed both type-checking and value checking -- for quantified expressions perhaps they do, but for function and predicate parameters perhaps they do only static type checking.  Your example is very helpful:  concise and clear.  On `in` and `extends`, you're right; normally I would use `extends` here.  In the full model, `in` is used to avoid some (tedious) technical complications omitted here.  (But even with `in`, the subset types are disjoint, owing to the redundancy with the `rc` field!)

Comment: I see your point, you're right, but even if the 3 kinds of response you have declared are disjoint thanks to the constraints on the rc field, they do not partition the set of all Responses, You might thus get unexpected Response atoms that have e.g. a rc field set to rc200 for example but that are not rc200_OK responses.
Anyway, I trust you know what you're doing :3